# I'm trying to convert somehow dicitionary in variable "question" to a text

Tags: python, html, dictionary, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to convert somehow dictionary which is in variable "question", to a text - string. I did try methods like "text" or "get_text()", but nothing works for me. I followed many tutorials but nothing helped. I am beginner in web scraping and Python too.

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'}

url = f'https://volby.cz/pls/ps2017nss/ps311?xjazyk=CZ&xkraj=6&xobec=566985&xokrsek=1&xvyber=4204'
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser')
questions = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'topline'})

for tag in questions:
    question = {
    "title": soup.find("h2").text,
    "location": soup.find_all("h3")[0:4],
    "table_1": soup.find_all("table")[0].get_text(),
    "table_2": soup.find_all("table")[1].get_text(),
    "table_3": soup.find_all("table")[2].get_text()
    }
    
    print(question)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: how do you want to put the tables in the text?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? We can directly convert dictionary to string by:

```
question = {
"title": soup.find("h2").text,
"location": " ".join(a.text for a in soup.find_all("h3")[0:4]),
"table_1": soup.find_all("table")[0].get_text(),
"table_2": soup.find_all("table")[1].get_text(),
"table_3": soup.find_all("table")[2].get_text()
}
```

Comment: Okey, it works, but methods like"text" doestn work for that, i need just clean text from scraped informations

Comment: You mean in the location right?

Comment: From every key in dictionary i need to have clean text. I am not sure if i scraped right way. I hope that i did.

Comment: I have modified the location. Take a look.

Comment: if u wanna clean text use - `get_text(strip=True)`  like - `"title": soup.find("h2").get_text(strip=True),` or `"location": " ".join(a.get_text(strip=True) for a in soup.find_all("h3")[0:4]),` etc.

Comment: I will try this last solution, for this time thanks both of you !! ♥